# Starting xmobar with keyboard shortcut after xmonad start

Tags: xmonad, xmobar

I'm trying to configure xmonad again witout any Haskell knowledge...

I would like to find a way to start xmonad without any statusbar at the beginning. I want to avoid running xmobar in the background
and drain battery. 
Then, when pressing meta-b xmobar should be started.
Does anyone know a keyboard shortcut definition for the xmonad config file
that starts xmobar and connect the pipes?

```
  ...  
  xmproc <- spawnPipe "xmobar ~/.xmonad/xmobar.hs"
  xmonad $ defaults  {
      logHook = dynamicLogWithPP $ xmobarPP {
            ppOutput = hPutStrLn xmproc
          , ppTitle = xmobarColor xmobarTitleColor "" . shorten 100
          , ppCurrent = xmobarColor xmobarCurrentWorkspaceColor ""
          , ppSep = "   "
      } 
  ...
```

is the standard one, but how can I define it as a keyboard shortcut?
When binding a simple  "spawn xmobar" it is not starting up (when starting xmobar it in a shell however the statusbar appears). However the simple "spawn xmobar" would probably not have the text from xmonad showing the workspaces connected.

Answer (score 0):

As of xmonad(-contrib) 0.9, there is a new statusBar function in XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog. It allows you to use your own configuration for:

- The command used to execute the bar
- The PP that determines what is being written to the bar
- The key binding to toggle the gap for the bar

The following is an example of how to use it:

~/.xmonad/xmonad.hs

```
-- Imports.
import XMonad
import XMonad.Hooks.DynamicLog

-- The main function.
main = xmonad =<< statusBar myBar myPP toggleStrutsKey myConfig

-- Command to launch the bar.
myBar = "xmobar"

-- Custom PP, configure it as you like. It determines what is being written to the bar.
myPP = xmobarPP { ppCurrent = xmobarColor "#429942" "" . wrap "<" ">" }

-- Key binding to toggle the gap for the bar.
toggleStrutsKey XConfig {XMonad.modMask = modMask} = (modMask, xK_b)

-- Main configuration, override the defaults to your liking.
myConfig = defaultConfig { modMask = mod4Mask }
```

For more information see the following link:
[Source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xmonad#More_configurable)